Strapi - The "path" argument must be of type string or an instance of Buffer or URL. Received null
15094 timing command:install Completed in 55491ms
15095 verbose stack TypeError [ERR_INVALID_ARG_TYPE]: The "path" argument must be of type string or an instance of Buffer or URL. Received null
15095 verbose stack     at open (node:internal/fs/promises:605:10)
15095 verbose stack     at writeFile (node:internal/fs/promises:1055:20)
15095 verbose stack     at Shrinkwrap.save (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/@npmcli/arborist/lib/shrinkwrap.js:1133:7)
15095 verbose stack     at [saveIdealTree] (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/@npmcli/arborist/lib/arborist/reify.js:1460:33)
15095 verbose stack     at Arborist.reify (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/@npmcli/arborist/lib/arborist/reify.js:176:31)
15095 verbose stack     at async Install.exec (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/lib/commands/install.js:152:5)
15095 verbose stack     at async module.exports (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/lib/cli-entry.js:61:5)
15096 verbose cwd /Users/my_name/Desktop/Dev/dir1/my_proj/backend
15097 verbose Darwin 23.1.0
15098 verbose node v20.11.0
15099 verbose npm  v10.2.4
15100 error code ERR_INVALID_ARG_TYPE
15101 error The "path" argument must be of type string or an instance of Buffer or URL. Received null
15102 verbose exit 1
15103 timing npm Completed in 55592ms
15104 verbose unfinished npm timer reify 1735051824827
15105 verbose unfinished npm timer reify:save 1735051880090
15106 verbose code 1
15107 error A complete log of this run can be found in: /Users/my_name/.npm/_logs/2024-12-24T14_50_24_725Z-debug-0.log

I'm getting this error when I try to run npm install on my strapi project. It seems to generate the node_modules but not the package-lock.json. My package.json is the following:
{
  "name": "backend",
  "private": true,
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "description": "A Strapi application",
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "strapi develop",
    "start": "strapi start",
    "build": "strapi build",
    "strapi": "strapi"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@ckeditor/strapi-plugin-ckeditor": "^0.0.11",
    "@strapi/plugin-cloud": "^4.22.0",
    "@strapi/plugin-documentation": "^4.22.0",
    "@strapi/plugin-i18n": "^4.22.0",
    "@strapi/plugin-users-permissions": "^4.22.0",
    "@strapi/provider-upload-aws-s3": "^4.22.0",
    "@strapi/strapi": "^4.22.0",
    "pg": "^8.11.5",
    "react": "^18.0.0",
    "react-dom": "^18.0.0",
    "react-router-dom": "5.3.4",
    "styled-components": "5.3.3"
  },
  "author": {
    "name": "A Strapi developer"
  },
  "strapi": {
    "uuid": "1362378d-c286-4075-9d7f-dbefb5306fae"
  },
  "engines": {
    "node": ">=18.0.0 <=20.x.x",
    "npm": ">=6.0.0"
  },
  "license": "MIT"
}

Any help? I have no idea what is going on here. I tried clearing the cache and reinstalling, but that didn't work either. I'm pretty sure it's something to do with the dependency tree, but I'm not too sure.
